# how to used IN & Between Clause in YII ACtive Record?

Tags: yii

I want write a Following Query in Active record .

```
SELECT *
FROM `User`
WHERE `UserId`
IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9 ) ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question......?

Comment: He is looking for the CActivRecord Syntax in Yii to geht an SQL Statement like this example.

Comment: Consider accepting answer for your question!

Answer (score 31):

You can use `CDbCriteria` statement:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('userId', array(6,7,8,9));
$result = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Is there a solution like that for [tag:yii2] ?

Answer (score 10):

You can put your array as a value for a specific attribute, like this (no tested):

```
$model=new User();
$result=$model->findAllByAttributes(array('UserId'=>array(6,7,8,9)));
```

Comment: Why new User()? Is that superior to User::model() in some way?

Comment: Hi Bob, user is the name of the model under protected/models/user.php

Comment: I think Bob was asking why do it in two lines instead of one `User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('UserId'=>array(6,7,8,9)));`?

Comment: @Bob Instancing the model is in my case default. But in this case it's not really necessary, you can use the static version `User::model()->...`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get your query faster, use Command Builder:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('user')
    ->where(array('in', 'UserId', array(6, 7, 8, 9)))
    ->queryAll();
```

To get it via CActiveRecord, use `findAllByAttributes`

```
User::model()
    ->findAllByAttributes(array(
         'UserId' => array(6,7,8,9)
    ));
```

But it will get full object of User with all associated relations, so it's slower.

Comment: `where(array('in', 'column_name', array())` saved me, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You might use both IN and BETWEEN statements thru CDbCriteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition("id", array(6,7,8,9));
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('id', '10', '20', 'OR');
$result = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

this will result in SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `User`
WHERE `id`
IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9 )
OR `id` BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Note the **4-th paramenter *OR*** in [addBetweenCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addBetweenCondition-detail) method; missing it, the default ***AND*** will be applied to concatenate that condition to the rest of WHERE-query.

P.S. Strictly speaking those `addBetweenCondition()` and `addInCondition()` methods should be added to an existing condition. So, you might need to set first a criteria's initial condition like this:

```
$criteria->condition = '1=1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I still using this way:

```
public function getInterval( $data_start, $data_stop ){
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->condition = "date  >= '$data_start' AND date <= '$data_stop'";
  return $criteria;
}
$model = Object::model()->findAll(getInterval('2014-06-01','2014-06-30');
```

Comment: isn't it exposed to SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

There is an function called `findAllBySql` in yii to run sql query and get the outputs.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `UserId` IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9 )";//Your Sql query
$value=User::model()->findAllBySql($sql);// "User" is the model belongs to the table 'User'
```

The "$value" will return the result in a array. To get the values you can use the following method.

```
foreach($value as $val){
   echo $val->UserId;
}
```

(or)

```
var index=0;
echo $val[$index]->UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use **addInCondition** or you can also use **compare** method.

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $criteria->compare('UserId',array(6,7,8,9));
 $userDataObj = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```