# Yii using a variable with an IN condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to pull information into a page using my model. The issue is that I need to use an `IN` condition on my mysql using a variable.

Here is the code I use currently

```
$list_id = '1,3';
$clients = ListSubscriber::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'list_id IN (:list_id)','params'=>array(':list_id'=>$list_id)));
```

I won't necessarily know how many numbers will be stored within `$list_id`, hence the need for a variable to work with the `IN`.

The code does execute without errors, but only seems to return the values for the first number of `$list_id`, so in this case it only finds users where the `list_id` = 1.

Any help is appreciated. I have found this question [Yii addInCondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564221/yii-addincondition)
However they are using static values, which does not resolve my issue.

When I do use static values, the code executes with results as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068006/how-to-used-in-between-clause-in-yii-active-record/6107617#6107617

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use addInCondition :

```
$list_id = '1,3';
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$arr_list_id = explode(",",$list_id);
$criteria->addInCondition("list_id ", $arr_list_id );
$clients = ListSubscriber::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: @lascort Is this comment for me?

Comment: nah I'm just backing up your solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
$list_ids = array(1,3);
$clients = ListSubscriber::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('list_id'=>$list_ids));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Voodoo417, I tested an it is working, however I have chosen Kumar_v's answer simply because Lascort agreed with his solution.