# Yii bind values for IN clause

Tags: mysql, data-binding, yii, sql-injection

For preventing SQL injection in Yii In clause we need to bind parameters in IN clause, but Yii CDB criteria queries dont have this functionality in built.

```
$products_ids = array(234,100,405,506);
```

map the array for binding

```
$in_query = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($products_ids), '?'));
```

Prepare the commadn object for select

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                 ->select('product_id, product_name, product_image, product_price')
                 ->from('products')
                 ->where('product_id IN(' . $in_query . ')');
```

bind the parameters

```
foreach ($products_ids as $k => $product_id){
     $command->bindValue(($k+1),$product_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

get the result

```
$products = $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an in condition with yii. I have used this today:

```
$orderIds = array(1,2);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition("order_id", $orderIds,'AND');
$criteria->condition = 'product_id = :product_id';
$criteria->params = array(':product_id'=>$product->id );
$orderItems=new CActiveDataProvider('OrderItems', array(
                                                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                                                    'pagination'=>array(
                                                        'pageSize'=>20,
                                                        ),
                                        ));
```

I have asked this question previously myself, see here:
[Yii using a variable with an IN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049522/yii-using-a-variable-with-an-in-condition)

I have put this as an answer rather than a comment as I also had issues using addInCondition with another condition also, this was due to not including the `'AND'` at the end as the addInCondition was replacing the params and giving me an error regarding Invalid Number of parameters. Hope this helps.